# String from a sql statement not working as text var in deepl lib for python

Tags: python, string, var, deepl

It seems i cannot hand over my text (pulled from a mssql database) in the deepls request.
It alway ends up with the error:
raise ValueError("text must not be empty")
ValueError: text must not be empty

How to fix this?
reading a variable works:

```py
mytextvar = "Hallo Guten Tag"
result = translator.translate_text(mytextvar,target_lang="EN-US")
```

but as soon as the string in the var iscoming from my mssql query, it will fail:

```py
query = ("SELECT sometextstring, moretext FROM tablexy ")
data = cursor.execute(query)
for i in data:
        text = (i[1])
        result = translator.translate_text(text,target_lang="EN-US")
        print(result)
```

I can even check type and get string for the text var after loading it with the value from (i[1])

So what am I missing here?

Basically i want to go through my table, read the text and translate it, then write it back...

Comment: The error says that `text` is empty, which means you have some rows in your table where the `moretext` column is empty/blank.  Fix your data, or adjust the code so that it doesn't call `translate_text()` in that case.

Comment: yeah, that would explain it. let me check
Thanks!

Comment: @JohnGordon works like a charm!
 I added a check before the deepl call - quite obvious after thinking about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given that your problem is `ValueError: text must not be empty`, you may be trying to translate empty values from your SQL database. A simple check to see if your query returned an empty value, try:

```
query = ("SELECT sometextstring, moretext FROM tablexy ")
data = cursor.execute(query)
for i in data:
        if i: # checks if string is not empty
             text = (i[1])
             result = translator.translate_text(text, target_lang="EN-US")
             print(result)
```